# Is it possible to create a shard key from an array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to create shard key from an array but it is showing me error -

> errmsg" : "can't shard collection 'inno.inno_pub' with unique index on
>   { mid: 1.0 } and proposed shard key { mid: 1.0, t.category: 1.0,
>   t.value: 1.0 }. "Uniqueness can't be maintained unless shard key is a
>   prefix"

Answer (score 2):

From [Kristina Chodorow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4243/kristina)'s book **[MongoDB - The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028031.do)**:

> Shard keys cannot be arrays. `sh.shardCollection()` will fail if any
>   key has an array value and inserting an array into that field is not
>   allowed. Once inserted, a document's shard key value cannot be
>   modified. To change a document's shard key, you must remove the
>   document, change the key, and reinsert it. Thus, you should choose a
>   field that is unchangeable or changes frequently.

Comment: MongoDB 4.2 allows changing the shard key value (assuming the shard key is not the immutable _id - which continues to remain unchangeable).  MongoDB4.4 allows redefining the shard key entirely.  Even so, shard keys cannot be based on arrays because each index entry is a potential split point for a chunk.  Given the array is part of a document you cannot split the document during chunk splitting.

Comment: @barrypicker **MongoDB4.4 allows _redefining_ the shard key**, it is not **_redefining_** it is _**refining**_

Answer (score 0):

As per release 4.4

Refinable shard keys are introduced, which simply means you can keep rebalancing with a more fine-grained level even after you've defined the shard ley by adding/suffix/appending the key for better distribution/cardinality as per the data growth/added new shards in cluster

Copied from the official [source](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/scale-without-fear-or-friction):

> MongoDB 4.4 brings the ability to [refine](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4/#refinable-shard-keys) the shard key itself, and to create compound hashed shard keys to allow for an even more fine-grained distribution of data within the cluster.

---

> Shard keys cannot be arrays. `sh.shardCollection()` will fail if any key has an array value and inserting an array into that field is not allowed.

Holds good with version 4.2

---

But, as an important note with the release of new version starting 4.2, the following statement does not apply.

> "Once inserted, a document's shard key value cannot be modified" .

So the answer to the question, **Can shard key be changed?**

> Although you cannot select a different shard key for a sharded collection, starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can update a document's shard key value unless the shard key field is the immutable _id field

Comment: MongoDB 4.4 introduces ability to redefine the shard key.

Comment: @barrypicker But this is just the flexibility to *refine* the shard key [not *redefine* as per your comment]. But thanks for commenting, which help me to update my answer